# I need to remove inner shadow when I click a button

Tags: swift, uibutton, shadow

**this is my extension that I use for add inner shadow into my button.
i create all case where I want my shadow into the button or my view.**

```
public extension UIView
```

{
    // different inner shadow styles
    public enum innerShadowSide
    {
        case  all, left, right, top, bottom, topAndLeft, topAndRight, bottomAndLeft, bottomAndRight, exceptLeft, exceptRight, exceptTop, exceptBottom
    }

```
// define function to add inner shadow
public func addInnerShadow(onSide: innerShadowSide, shadowColor: UIColor, shadowSize: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0, shadowOpacity: Float) -> CAShapeLayer

{
    // define and set a shaow layer
    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.frame = bounds
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowSize
    shadowLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    // define shadow path
    let shadowPath = CGMutablePath()

    // define outer rectangle to restrict drawing area
    let insetRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: -shadowSize * 2.0, dy: -shadowSize * 2.0)

    // define inner rectangle for mask
    let innerFrame: CGRect = { () -> CGRect in
        switch onSide
        {

        case .all:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        case .left:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 4.0)
        case .right:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 4.0)
        case .top:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 4.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case.bottom:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 4.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .topAndLeft:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .topAndRight:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .bottomAndLeft:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .bottomAndRight:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .exceptLeft:
            return CGRect(x: -shadowSize * 2.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height)
        case .exceptRight:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width + shadowSize * 2.0, height: frame.size.height)
        case .exceptTop:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -shadowSize * 2.0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        case .exceptBottom:
            return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height + shadowSize * 2.0)
        }
    }()

    // add outer and inner rectangle to shadow path
    shadowPath.addRect(insetRect)
    shadowPath.addRect(innerFrame)

    // set shadow path as show layer's
    shadowLayer.path = shadowPath

    // add shadow layer as a sublayer
    layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)

    // hide outside drawing area
    clipsToBounds = true

    return shadowLayer

}
```

}
I use this code like this when I see for the first time my button:
in this case I want to have the shadow into all my button and I use the black color.

```
var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer?

            self.shadowLayer = okButton.addInnerShadow(onSide: UIView.innerShadowSide.all, shadowColor: UIColor.black, shadowSize: 10.0, shadowOpacity: 10.0)
```

I need to remove this inner shadow when I click my button into my function:

```
       @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1
    {
        statoBici = "ok"
        print(statoBici)
        setConfermaButton()
        self.shadowLayer.removeFromSuperLayer()


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your UIView function to return CAShapeLayer:

```
public func addInnerShadow(onSide: innerShadowSide, shadowColor: UIColor, shadowSize: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0, shadowOpacity: Float) -> CAShapeLayer
{
.
.
. 
  return shadowLayer
}
```

Then add a variable or member variable to your class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    self.shadowLayer = btnShadow.addInnerShadow(onSide: UIView.innerShadowSide.all, shadowColor: UIColor.black, shadowSize: 10.0, shadowOpacity: 10.0)
  }
}
```

And finally , remove the shadow layer from your button:

```
  @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton
        {
          if btn.tag == 1 {
            self.shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
          }
        }
      }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Value of type 'CAShapeLayer' has no member 'removeFromSuperLayer'
i have this error

Comment: CAShapeLayer is derived from CALayer and it has the removeFromSuperLayer function.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer

Comment: did you declare shadowLayer as CAShapeLayer!  and not  CAShapeLayer?

Comment: doesn't work I have the same error "Value of type 'CAShapeLayer?' has no member 'removeFromSuperLayer'"

Comment: can you please post the code, it is compiling on my side and removing the shadow.

Comment: I have just modified my code, can you check if I have done all the steps well?

Comment: I use IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton)  not  IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {

Comment: this declaration is incorrect: var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer?
it should be var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer!

check my code.

Comment: change the question mark (?) to exclamation point (!) in var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer!

Comment: I modified from var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer? to var shadowLayer : CAShapeLayer! but doesn't work

Comment: did you have a tag to your button? try debugging it and see if it goes to your btnAction function. working on my side

Comment: I have attached the screenshots showing the shadow removed. try removing the if condition for tag and see if it works.

Comment: ok now it's work. can I modify different button with other tag? I modify you code with description check your code please.

Comment: yep. that is okay.

Comment: check now please

Comment: you don't have to modify my answer as long as it is working for you now. mine is just a sample on how I did it. :) your code is different as you are using a different UIButton class. I just re-created your env to help you solve the issue.

Comment: no worries. if your code is working now then please accept my answer on this post. :) and yes, your code is fine.

Comment: ok, done. if I have different button with tag 1 and tag 2. can I remove the shadow into the opposite button? if I click btn.tag 1 remove to btn.tag 2  and  in reverse

Comment: yes, you can . as long as you add that shadowLayer to your target button , it will work. If you want to add the shadow layer to btn 2 then call the addInnerShadow function on btn2.

Comment: IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton
        {
            if btn.tag == 1
            {
// here remove to btn.tag 2
                self.shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()      
            }else if btn.tag == 2
            {
// here remove to btn.tag 1
                self.shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()      
            }
// btn.tag 1 called okButton
// btn.tag 2 called okPrivacyButton
what should I write instead of self.shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()  to indicate the exact button